# Javascript / Jest: test that previously passes now fails when moving object to external helper

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I have a test where I define a `player` object in the `beforeEach`.  In my test, after each `jest.advanceTimersByTime(2001)` call, `player.seekable.mock.calls` increments so since I call `jest.advanceTimersByTime(2001)` two times, the `player.seekable.mock.calls.length` is 2.

**initPlayer.test.js**

```
describe('testing', () => {
   let player, seekableEnd;
   
   beforeEach(() => {

       seekableEnd = 120;

       player = {
          currentTime: jest.fn(),
          seekable: jest.fn(() => {
             return {
                end: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(seekableEnd),
             };
          }),
       } 
   });

    it('should keep until the video has a seekable edge', async () => {
    
       seekableEnd = undefined;
       player.currentTime.mockReturnValue(10);

       await initPlayer();

       jest.advanceTimersByTime(2001);
       seekableEnd = 100;
       jest.advanceTimersByTime(2001);

       expect(player.seekable.mock.calls.length).toBe(2);
  });
});
```

---

I wanted to extract `player` into a helper so that I'm not defining it in the test.  I did that below but when I use the helper in my test file, `player.seekable.mock.calls.length` is `1` rather than `2`, which it was when `player` is defined in the test directly....I have no idea why.

**player.js**

```
export function getPlayer(data) {

       player = {
          currentTime: jest.fn(),
          seekable: jest.fn(() => {
             return {
                end: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(data.seekableEnd),
             };
          }),
       } 

    }

 export default getPlayer;
```

**initPlayer.test.js**

```
import { getPlayer } from './helpers/player';

describe('testing', () => {
   let player, seekableEnd;

   beforeEach(() => {

       seekableEnd = 120;

       const data = { seekableEnd };
       player = getPlayer(data);
   });

    it('should keep until the video has a seekable edge', async () => {

       seekableEnd = undefined;
       player.currentTime.mockReturnValue(10);

       await initPlayer();

       jest.advanceTimersByTime(2001);
       seekableEnd = 100;
       jest.advanceTimersByTime(2001);

       expect(player.seekable.mock.calls.length).toBe(2);   <---- this is 1 now when using the extracted player helper
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`getPlayer`is not returning the player object. Try changing it to:

```
export function getPlayer(data) {

   return {
      currentTime: jest.fn(),
      seekable: jest.fn(() => {
         return {
            end: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(data.seekableEnd),
         };
      }),
   } 
}

export default getPlayer;
```